# Scroll top in animate function resting top position in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scroll top in animate function resting top position in IE. See my script given below.

**My Script**

```
//Scroll Using Click
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Add smooth scrolling to all links
                $('.scrollTo').on('click', function (event) {
                    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                    if (this.hash !== "") {
                        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                        event.preventDefault();
                        // Store hash
                        var hash = this.hash;

                        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
                        }, 800, function () {
                            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                            window.location.hash = hash;
                        });
                    } // End if
                });
            });
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Please elaborate.  Description is insufficient.

Comment: I have set scroll top position,  where scroll side or section will stop scrolling. Scroll top position is working in other browsers, but not in IE browser. See image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/e54yO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE browser scroll top position issue solved  by removing function from animate function.